# Aptana studio 3 on mac, set file encoding to windows 1250

Tags: aptana3, cp1250

I've recently switched to mac, but I'm having problems working on my previous project. It has Windows 1250(cp-1250) encoding.

Is it possible to change encoding on mac Aptana to use cp1250? I can't see it in `Aptana->Preferences->General->Workspace`. Is it only supported on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

My friend just told me about how to do it. If anybody else need this. All you have to do is write it in the dropdown box where you select encodings.