# How to change charset to CP1250 in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: character-encoding, aptana, cp1250

I used PSPad with CP1250 charset and now i switch to Aptana Studio 3 and I have problem with encoding. Is it possible to add new charset to Aptana? Because, in Aptana are charsets UTF-8, UTF-16 and ISO-8859-1 but no one works.
(Sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the encoding for your project under Project > Properties > Resource > Text File Encoding. There is an option to inherit from container, or to select from a dropdown (you can also type a new encoding type into this box).

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209144/solved-aptana-studio-3-on-mac-set-file-encoding-to-windows-1250).